# Apply javascript function to every row of a table using the cell value as a parameter?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, timer, countdown

I have a table (generated from a php array) that shows a users current auctions. One of the columns of this table shows the time remaining in the auction. I am using a jquery countdown plugin (http://www.keith-wood.name/countdown.html) that makes the remaining time countdown to zero.

How can I apply the countdown function to every row using the different remaining times?

```
$(function () {
    $('#countdown').countdown({until: +remainingTime, format: 'HMS', compact: true});
});
```

what I am trying, but doesn't seem to be working:

```
 foreach($tradePile['auctionInfo'] as $auction)
 {                      
     if ($auction['tradeState'] == "active")
     {
        $i++;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="player.php?id='.$auction['itemData']['resourceId']. '">'.$stats['first_name'].' '.$stats['last_name'].'</a></td>';
        echo'<td>'.$auction['itemData']['rating'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$buyNowPrice.'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$auction['startingBid'].'</td>'; 
        //remaining time for each auction:
        //$auction['expires']
        ?>
        <td>
           <script>$(function () {$('#countdown<?php echo $i; ?>').countdown({until: +<?php echo $auction['expires'] ?>, format: 'HMS', compact: true});});</script>
           <div id="countdown<?php echo $i; ?>"></div>
        </td>
        <?php
        echo'</tr>';
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use each to loop through all the table row.
Do not write JS script with PHP.

Create table structure like this defining the id with your incremental `i` variable:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="1" expire="55">
    <td id="countdown-1">....</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

And JS code like that :

```
$(function () {
    $('#myTable tr').each(function(){
        var remainingTime = $(this).attr('expire');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#countdown-'+id).countdown({until: +remainingTime, format: 'HMS', compact: true});
    });
});
```